# VSTO Write Dictionary To Range Extension Method

Tags: c#, excel, hash-map, interval

I was hoping to receive some criticism on this block of code. I wrote it to write the contents of a dictionary to excel range in VSTO. It works well. I am interested to see how people could improve it.  What would you do differently to make it more expressive, efficient?

```
public static void WriteToRange(this Dictionary<string, object[]> DicToRange, excel.Range toRange)
    {
       object[,] storeDictionaryData = new object[DicToRange.Max(maxValues=> maxValues.Value.Length),DicToRange.Count];

       int keyCounter=0;
       int valueCounter =0;



       foreach (var key in DicToRange.Keys)
       {
         if (keyCounter < storeDictionaryData.GetLength(1))
           {
               foreach (var value in DicToRange[key])
               {
                   if (valueCounter < storeDictionaryData.GetLength(0))
                   {
                       storeDictionaryData[valueCounter, keyCounter] = value;
                       valueCounter++;
                   }
               }

               keyCounter++;
               valueCounter = 0;
           }
       }

       dynamic rangeToFill=toRange.get_Resize(storeDictionaryData.GetLength(0), storeDictionaryData.GetLength(1));
       rangeToFill.Value = storeDictionaryData;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You have a lot of unnecessary vertical spacing which should be removed to improve readability.

---

Based on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) input parameter should be named using `camelCase` casing.

---

Because `WriteToRange()` can be called also as a normal static method you need to check both input parameters for `null`.

---

The `storeDictionaryData` is basically a `object[columns, rows]` this should be reflected by the counter variables. You can just rename them `valueCounter -> column`, `keyCounter -> row`.

---

You don't need the checks `keyCounter < storeDictionaryData.GetLength(1)` and `valueCounter < storeDictionaryData.GetLength(0)` because at the point where you create the array you have taken care of the upper bounds of both dimensions. Both conditions won't evaluate to false.

---

`toRange` is poorly named. Consider to name it `destinationRange` or simply `destination`. Then a good pattern would be also to rename `DictToRange` to `source`.

---

You should allow your variables to breathe by adding spaces between variables and operators.

---

Taking the above points into account we can refactor the method to

```
public static void WriteToRange(this Dictionary<string, object[]> source, excel.Range destination)
{
   if (source == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("source"); }
   if (destination == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("destination"); }
   if (source.Count == 0) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("source"); }

   object[,] storeDictionaryData = new object[source.Max(maxValues => maxValues.Value.Length), source.Count];

   int column = 0;
   int row = 0;

   foreach (var key in source.Keys)
   {
       foreach (var value in source[key])
       {
           storeDictionaryData[column, row] = value;
           column++;
       }

       row++;
       column = 0;
   }

   dynamic rangeToFill = destination.get_Resize(storeDictionaryData.GetLength(0), storeDictionaryData.GetLength(1));
   rangeToFill.Value = storeDictionaryData;
}
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing!! You have given megreat information to learn from. Let me review it alltonight. Thanks Heslacher!

Answer (score 5):

Adding to [@Heslacher's excellent review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/78879/23788), I would say that there is one thing in the signature that tickles reusability and extensibility:

```
public static void WriteToRange(this Dictionary<string, object[]> DicToRange, excel.Range toRange)
```

Do you see it?

That's right: `this Dictionary<string, object[]>` is the main reason for missing a heartbeat here.

***Extend interfaces!*** You're extending a *specific implementation* of the `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` interface. This means I can't use this extension method on a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>`, or a `Sorted<TKey,TValue>`, or any other possible implementation of `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` ever written - and more importantly, those not written *yet*, too.

By extending a concrete type, you're... missing out on the best of extension methods.

Comment: Again - I am so grateful for that input. I did not even know to think of that, but now I made a concrete note of it.

Comment: so I should be doing something like this: public static void WriteToRange(this IDictionary<string, object[]> DicToRange, excel.Range toRange).